# My sql query is giving me a error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$query = " 
SELECT * 
  FROM comments 
 WHERE comment_post_id = {$The_post_id} 
   AND comment_status = 'approved' 
";
```

error is

> errorYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'AND comment_status='approved'' at line 1

Comment: if $the_post_id is not an int you need quotes around it

Comment: And if it is missing, then you get the error message as described.

Comment: it is a integer Daniel Marcus

Comment: the approved keyword is in the database  Shadow

Comment: good way to debug `echo $query`

Comment: thnk you i will try it smith

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: It's highly probable that `$The_post_id` is not set and you have a query string of the form `WHERE x= AND y=z` which is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

if `{$The_post_id}` always returns an integer and `comment_post_id` is an INT column then it's probably because PHP is not substituting the variable correctly.

As suggested in the comments you need to debug this by printing out the query once the variable has been substituted.

Comment: it was a syntax error in $The_post_id , it is $the_post_id